# Calculate $\iint_{D_r} (Q_x (x,y) - P_y(x,y)) dx dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

Consider $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ twice derivable and the vector field $F(x,y) = (P(x,y),Q(x,y))$, with $P(x,y) = x\,g(x,y)$, $Q(x,y) = y\,g(x,y)$. If $D_r$ is a disc with center of origin and radius $r>0$, so  $\iint_{D_r} (Q_x (x,y) - P_y(x,y)) dx dy$ is equal to:

(A) $\pi r^2$

(B) $2\pi r$

(C) $r$

(D) $1$

->**(E)** **$0$**

> I tried to this form:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Green's theorem
$$\eqalign{\int_{D_r}(Q_x-P_y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)&=\int_{\partial D_r}P\>dx+Q\>dy\cr &=\int_{\partial D_r}g(x,y)\bigl(x\>dx+y\>dy)\cr  &={1\over2}\int_{\partial D_r}g(x,y)\>d(x^2+y^2)=0\ .\cr}$$
If the last steps look like magic plug in a parametric representation $$\phi\mapsto (r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)\qquad(0\leq\phi\leq 2\pi)$$ of $\partial D_r$. The pullback of $x\,dx+y\,dy$ then evaluates to $0$:
$$x\>dx+y\>dy=x(\phi)x'(\phi)+y(\phi)y'(\phi)=r^2\bigl(\cos\phi(-\sin\phi)+\sin\phi\cos\phi\bigr)\equiv0\ .$$

By the way: The field $${\bf F}({\bf z})=\bigl(P({\bf z}),Q({\bf z})\bigr)=g({\bf z})\,{\bf z}$$ is orthogonal to $d{\bf z}$ in all points  ${\bf z}\in\partial D_r$.

Comment: should you explain the last line? I cant realize that this integral is zero in the first place.

Comment: Never mind! I got the point of line integral over the circle (closed) and conservative field. Thank you.

Comment: The field $(P,Q)$ is not conservative, but at all points orthogonal to $d{\bf z}$.

Comment: The last transformation on polar coordinates is very clear to me but i'd rather to undestand how the field F is ortogonal on entire $\partial D_r$

Answer (score 1):

By the way,
\begin{align*}
&\iint Q_{x}-P_{y}\\
&=\int Pdx+Qdy\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(r\cos\theta)g(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)(-r\sin\theta)+(r\sin\theta)g(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)r\cos\theta d\theta \\
&=0.
\end{align*}

Comment: I did this in my resolution but I staked here: $\int y g(x,y) dy - \int x g(x,y) dx$.

Comment: @miguel747, wrong. You aren't using Green's theorem (nor line integrals).

Comment: Some $r$ are missing.